# Where can I download Coldfusion MX 7 for Mac?

Tags: macos, coldfusion, coldfusion-7, coldfusion-6

It seems like it is no longer downloadable from Adobe, so I was wondering if anyone out there knows where I can download it from.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from Adobe here:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=coldfusion7

Answer (score 0):

Time to upgrade to ColdFusion 9. If that is not an option, I would encourage you to download ColdFusion 9 (or an open source CFML engine like Railo) and develop code using only the features and syntax allowed in CF7.

There are many reasons to upgrade from ColdFusion 7 to ColdFusion 9. The improvements can help save many hours from development--and programmers/time usually costs more than the the upgrade fee. If money is a difficulty here, Railo is a good alternative--some would argue an equal one.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Watts has advised on the cf-talk list that Figleaf is an authorised distributor of old versions. Try following up with him.

http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/message.cfm/messageid:339621

Answer (score 0):

Note that ColdFusion MX 7 for mac only works on PPC-based macs.